# Can i put off-road tires on a road focused hybrid?

Tags: tire, compatibility, hybrid-bike

I have recently bough a Nishiki Comp race hybrid that's more road focused. I have been using MTBs my whole life so it's pretty weird. Is there any way to put off-road tires on it also, it has 28" rims and it's that really narrow type.

Comment: The link should contain all you need. Even if we wanted to tell you something more specific to your bike, we can't, we do not have enough information about your bike. Check the rim internal width and also check the clearance you have between the tyre and the frame. If you have disc brakes, you are fine, if rime brakes, you also have to consider their clearance.